# How a CAN Bus addressing works?

Tags: can-bus

How a CAN Bus controller decides based on message identifier that this particular message belongs to it?Is it like the receiver already know that if identifier has suppose value 5 then its for me . And we program receiver to tell it that you should be interested in value 5 ?

Answer (score 2):

The software in the CAN node must decide what message IDs it is interested in, based on the network specification which is usually some kind of document or other electronic representation of which messages contain what sorts of information.  If a message arrives that is of no interest, it simply does not process it and the software returns to what it was doing just before the message arrived (assuming interrupt driven CAN handling).

Some CAN controllers (ie the part of the chip which does the CAN protocol transmission and reception) have message filtering which means that uninteresting messages can be dropped before they reach the software.  Other controllers have message filtering which can be set to accept only a single message ID in a particular "message box", and these can be configured to accept the messages you are interested in.   Again, other messages are dropped.  Some controllers have both filters and message boxes.

Answer (score 0):

At the CAN protocol level all nodes in a CAN network are equal and make a decision about whether to process a message or not. A "CAN controller" is a higher-level concept; it still needs to examine the message identifier like any other node.

Note that "processing" a message is different to the CAN protocol message check and acknowledgement. All nodes take part in that processing unless they're in "listen only" mode.

Update:

How you decide which message to process depends on what you are trying to do and the higher level protocol in use over CAN. In principle you mask out the ID bits that are relevant and then test them to see whether the message should be processed.

For example if you want to process all messages with 5 (binary 0101) in the low order four bits, your mask is 15 (binary 1111), you binary-and this with the received message ID, and then you compare the result with five.

For example:

```
(msg_id & 15) == 5
```

is a way of coding that test. Which bits you care about, and your implementation details depend on many other factors.

Comment: My question is how a node make a decision about whether to process a message or not.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for PDU1 (Protocol Data Unit) messages, a destination address is specified (byte 3). If a device receives a message not addressed to it, it can simply ignore it. Addresses are assigned by various standards, or a manufacturer may assign them ad-hoc.

In the general case the CAN-ID (bytes 0-4) contains all the details about what kind of message it is, and devices can inspect particular fields to decide whether they care about the message. For example the transmission controller probably doesn't care about battery status messages, nor the fuel gauge about which doors are locked.